# JNI MMAP memory leak

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mmap

I have a Pro*C application that communicates JAVA through JNI. The application performance degraded as application run for couple of days continuously. I perform the experiment and in Sun analyzer I found that mmap is leaking 94% of memory. 
Can anyone guide me me who eliminate or minimize the memory leak?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the memory mapping in Java.  This has an automatic cleanup on GC.

If you can't change the C code, then you need to debug that as that appears to be the cause of your bug. (In which case I would change the tag from `[Java]` to `[C]`

Comment: Thank you peter. Can u please explain this memory mapping ? Sorry I m a newbie to JAVA and JNI

Comment: Using memory mapping or JNI are fairly advanced topics which experts with ten years experience would avoid as being too complicated. Unless you are an expert in C (which is where I suspect the real problem is) I would suggest you try finding another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks again.Well solution has been implemented so going to memory map is not feasible. How can I carry from this point like JNI calls has memory issue

Comment: I would write a C program which calls the library in a realistic manner and debug/profiler this as a pure C program. Trying to use Java and C at the same time is likely to be very complex and difficult to resolve. If it doesn't work correctly as a stand alone C program it won't work through JNI.